# Evaluate the Integral $\int\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral:$$\int\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}}dx$$

My approach:

$$y:=\sqrt{3x+2}\Rightarrow dy=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3x+2}}\\\therefore x=\frac{y^2-2}{3}$$

Rewriting the integral in terms of $y$:

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}}dx{
=\frac{2}{3}\int\sqrt{\frac{2y^2-1}{3}}dy\\
=\frac{2\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3}\int\sqrt{y^2-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}dy\\
=\frac{2\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3}\left(\frac{y}2\sqrt{y^2-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}-\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|y+\sqrt{y^2-\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\right)^2}\right|\right)+c\\
=\frac{2\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(3x+2)(2x+1)}\sqrt3}{2\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\sqrt{3x+2}+\sqrt{3x+\frac{3}2}\right|\right)+c\\
=\frac{1}3\sqrt{(3x+2)(2x+1)}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{6}}\ln\left|\sqrt{3x+2}+\sqrt{3x+\frac{3}2}\right|+c}$$

But , answer in the book is: $$\frac{1}3\sqrt{(3x+2)(2x+1)}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{6}}\ln\left|\sqrt{2x+1}+\sqrt{2x+\frac{4}3}\right|+c$$

It is an indefinite integral so answer may defer. But, it dosen't look the same.

Comment: I would recommend to check your answer by derivation.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak , I have tried to diffentiate it but it is more tough than the integration.

Comment: Colleague @Ian already posted an answer, i.e. your approach is correct. Next, for such integrals I prefer this substitution: $t=\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}$. Now we can easily find $x=\frac{2t-1}{2-3t}$, and $\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{(2-3t)^2}\mathrm dt$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, $\int{\frac{\sqrt t}{(2-3t)^2}}dt$ is again a problematic integral.

Comment: To @O M: Ok. At least we are aware that math offer to us an alternative approaches, and some are more or less problematic, i.e. more or less beautiful.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak, Great comment. I am just a math beginner. I am hopeful to get help from you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3x+\frac{3}{2}=\frac{3}{2}(2x+1)$ and $3x+2=\frac{3}{2} \left ( 2x + \frac{4}{3} \right )$, so the arguments of the two logs differ by a constant factor (namely $\sqrt{3/2}$), meaning that the logs themselves differ by a constant (namely $\ln(\sqrt{3/2})$). Since everything else is the same, the results without the $+c$'s differ by a constant. So these answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[n]{\dfrac{a\,x+b}{c\,x+d}}$ With a common denominator of powers $\left(\dfrac{2\,x+1}{3\,x+2}\right)^{\mathbf{n}}$ with $\mathbf{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}$ and $p=2$

$$\def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{c|c}u=\dfrac{\sqrt{2\,x+1}}{\sqrt{3\,x+2}}&x=\dfrac{1-2\,{u}^{2}}{3\,{u}^{2}-2}\\&\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2\,u}{\left({3\,{u}^{2}-2}\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\end{array}$$
$$\int{\dfrac{2\,{u}^{2}}{\left({3\,{u}^{2}-2}\right)^{2}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
Integration by parts $\int{fg'}=fg-\int{f'g}$
$$\def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{c|c}f=u&g'=\dfrac{u}{\left({3\,{u}^{2}-2}\right)^{2}}\\f'=1&g=\,{\displaystyle\int{\dfrac{u}{\left({3\,{u}^{2}-2}\right)^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}u}=\dfrac{1}{6}\,\int{\dfrac{1}{\left({3\,{u}^{2}-2}\right)^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}=-\dfrac{1}{6\,\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}}\end{array}$$
$$2\left(-\dfrac{u}{6\,\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}+\int{\dfrac{1}{6\,\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}\right)=$$
=-$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}\right|\right)}{2\,\sqrt{2}\,3\,\sqrt{3}}+\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{3}\,u-\sqrt{2}\right|\right)}{2\,\sqrt{2}\,3\,\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{u}{3\,\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}$$

Notes

$$\int{\dfrac{1}{6\,\left(3\,{u}^{2}-2\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{6}\int{\dfrac{1}{3\,\left({u}^{2}-\dfrac{2}{3}\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{18}\int{\dfrac{1}{\left(u-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\,\left(u+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$

Grouping
$$1=-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,\sqrt{2}}\,\left(\left(u-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\left(u+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)$$
$$\dfrac{1}{18}\int{-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\,\left(\dfrac{1}{u+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}-\dfrac{1}{u-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\right)}{2\,\sqrt{2}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{18}\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,\sqrt{2}}\int{\dfrac{1}{u+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2\,\sqrt{2}}\int{\dfrac{1}{u-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}\right)=$$

$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{3}\,u-\sqrt{2}\right|\right)}{4\,\sqrt{2}\,3\,\sqrt{3}}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}\right|\right)}{4\,\sqrt{2}\,3\,\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\int{\dfrac{1}{u+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
$$\int{\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}}}{\;\mathrm{d}u}$$
$$\def\arraystretch{2}\begin{array}{c|c}v=\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}&u=\dfrac{v-\sqrt{2}}
{\sqrt{3}}\\&\mathrm{d}u=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\,\mathrm{d}v\end{array}$$
$$\sqrt{3}\int{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}\,v}}{\;\mathrm{d}v}$$

Substitution
$$\begin{array}{c|c}v=\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}&u=\dfrac{v-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\end{array}$$

$$\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{3}\,u+\sqrt{2}\right|\right)$$